# NMS FormMail.pl "Error: Bad or Missing Recipient"

Tags: html, perl, cgi, formmail

I'm trying to set up a simple form mailer script for my website, using NMS FormMail.pl. No matter what I do, it gives me an error saying:

> **Error: Bad or Missing Recipient**
>
> There was no recipient or an invalid recipient specified in the data sent to FormMail. Please make sure you have filled in the recipient form field with an e-mail address that has been configured in @recipients or @allow_mail_to. More information on filling in recipient/allow_mail_to form fields and variables can be found in the README file.

The thing is, I've made sure countless times that the recipient field on the form is *exactly* the same as what I have in the @allow_mail_to part of the script. I've tried grabbing the latest version of the script, copy-pasting the email addresses from the form to the script and vice versa, putting \'s before the @ and . in the email and taking them out, and even taking out the recipient field on the form (when I do that it still gives me the error despite the Readme saying it would just send to whoever was first in the @allow_mail_to field).

Below is the config I have for the script as well as the form tags:

```
  BEGIN
{
  $DEBUGGING         = 1;
  $emulate_matts_code= 0;
  $secure            = 1;
  $allow_empty_ref   = 1;
  $max_recipients    = 1;
  $mailprog          = '/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t';
  $postmaster        = '';
  @referers          = qw(--.com);
  @allow_mail_to     = qw(steven@--.com --.com localhost);
  @recipients        = ();
  %recipient_alias   = ();
  @valid_ENV         = qw(REMOTE_HOST REMOTE_ADDR REMOTE_USER HTTP_USER_AGENT);
  $locale            = '';
  $charset           = 'iso-8859-1';
  $date_fmt          = '%A, %B %d, %Y at %H:%M:%S';
  $style             = '/css/nms.css';
  $no_content        = 0;
  $double_spacing    = 1;
  $wrap_text         = 0;
  $wrap_style        = 1;
  $address_style     = 1;
  $send_confirmation_mail = 0;
  $confirmation_text = <<'END_OF_CONFIRMATION';
From: you@your.com
Subject: form submission

Thank you for your form submission.

END_OF_CONFIRMATION

# You may need to uncomment the line below and adjust the path.
# use lib './lib';

# USER CUSTOMISATION SECTION
# --------------------------
# Place any custom code here



# USER CUSTOMISATION << END >>
# ----------------------------
# (no user serviceable parts beyond here)
}
```

The recipient form field:

```
<input name="recipient" type="hidden" id="recipient" value="steven@--.com">
```

If it helps, I used Dreamweaver CS6 to create the site, including the form. I used Notepad to modify FormMail.pl. The server this is running on is Apache.

Comment: Could you catch the recipient value before the error and look at it?

Comment: Is `--.com` you disguising the domain name before posting it here? Is the real domain name different to that?

Comment: **@wk.:** the error says this: `The recipient was: [ steven@--.com`

Comment: @DaveCross: Yes, it is. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using TFmail.pl by the same guys instead of FormMail.pl and that ended up working just fine.